# Using Hashtags in Wordpress Nav Menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a single page site and I'm looking for a wordpress solution to create links to every post. as an example, I would like to achieve something like this

```
<ul id="navigation" class="menu1">
    <li><a href="#post-1">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post-2">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post-3">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#post-4">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

The solutions that I have seen so far deal with editing .htaccess or they are not permanent.

How can I achieve something like this on a theme level?

Here is a theme that was able to achieve what I'm trying to do: http://themes.mdnw.net/?theme=shapeshifter

If you click the links on the left (except blog) it just scrolls up and down the website.  How do I set up the navigation like this?

Comment: As this is a JavaScript enhanced menu, go and check out their scripts – then come back and ask for that part of the scripts you don't understood.

Comment: A hashtag is a shortcut for searching for content on Twitter. Those are fragment identifiers (and existed long before Twitter's user base came up with hashtags).

Comment: How many posts are there going to be? And will there constantly be new ones, or can you just hardcode the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery like this:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link_href = $(this).attr('href');
    var post_id = link_href.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    $.scrollTo('#post-' + post_id, 800);
});
```

When a navigation link is clicked, the POST number / id is extracted from href hash #post-432 for example. and use the [$.scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to scroll to the div with same post number/ID.

Here is a sample code to generate navigation menu from set of posts.

```
<ul id="navigation" class="menu1">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You still need to query the content of every post. similar query should do the trick and fetching `the_content()`